# How can I convert bulk of xml schema file to JSON file using Typescript?

Tags: node.js, json, xml, typescript, xmlschema

I should build a code of converting xml schema file to JSON file with Typescript.
I am adding a screenshot of xml schema file as a reference.

The thing is I am very lost what I should start for this project.
I am going to deal with Typescript, so I understand I need to define tag of xml files.
But I have no idea how to do it and how to start it.

Please give me some guidance and advices for helping me solving this problem! (Please!!)

Comment: Can you show an example of XML-schema and how JSON- file should look like?

Comment: Sure!!! I have no idea why the screenshot does not show up!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690795/need-guidance-how-can-i-convert-bulk-of-xml-schema-file-to-json-file-using-type
I reuploaded this questions with pics!!

And for the JSON file, there is no specific shape in my mind!
Please take a look!!! Thanks!!!:)

Comment: @Anatoly What I am really curios is how to define type of bulk of xml files! Cause all files have different factors...so I am very lost how to define types...and what I should do first for this project... So if you figure out, please let me know! I am welcome to listen your guidance and advice!!!:) Thanks!